# What is the purpose of include guards in headers?

Tags: c++, header-files, include-guards

In C++, what is the purpose of include guards in a header?

I have read that it is for preventing including files again and again, but how do header guard guarantee this

Comment: Wikipedia gives [a very good explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) of how include guards work.

Comment: The accepted term for this in C++ is "include guard".

Comment: What is the purpose? To *guard* against multiple inclusion. So if 10 files include the same header it is only included once preventing multiple *declarations* of variables, functions, etc.. that the header provieds.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The guard header (or more conventionally "include guard") is to prevent problems if header file is included more than once; e.g.

```
#ifndef MARKER
#define MARKER
// declarations 
#endif
```

The first time this file is `#include`-ed, the `MARKER` preprocessor symbol will be undefined, so the preprocessor will define the symbol, and the following declarations will included in the source code seen by the compiler.  On subsequent `#include`'s, the `MARKER` symbol will be defined, and hence everything within the `#ifndef` / `#endif` will be removed by the preprocessor.

For this to work properly, the `MARKER` symbol needs to be different for each header file that might possibly be `#include`-ed.

The reason this kind of thing is necessary is that it is illegal in C / C++ to define a type or function with the same name more than once in a compilation unit.  The guard allows you to `#include` a header file without worrying if has already been included.  Without the guard, multiple inclusions of the same header file would lead to unwanted redeclarations and compilation errors.  This is particularly helpful when header files need to `#include` other header files.

---

In short, it doesn't *prevent* you from `#include`-ing a file again and again.  Rather, it *allows* you to do this *without causing compilation errors*.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of header guards is to prevent issues where some code may appear only once per translation unit.

One example is a struct.  You cannot redefine a struct even if the second definition is identical.  So, if you try to compile the following:

```
struct foo { int x; };
struct foo { int x; };
```

The compiler will fail because of the redefinition.

It can be hard to guarantee you only include a header one time (this happens when headers include other headers).  If your header has struct definition, this will cause the compile to fail.  Header guards are the easy trick so that even if a header is included multiple times, it's contents only appear a single time.

Answer (score 2):

The modern C++ best practice to prevent violation of the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) is to use the directive `#pragma once`, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=msvc-170).

`#pragma once` is preferred over preprocessor macro definitions (i.e., `#ifndef`, `#define`, and `#endif`) because it doesn't pollute the global namespace and requires less typing.

**Caveat**: Even though `#pragma once` is currently supported by [the vast majority of modern compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), it is still [non-standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl). There might be portability issues where old compilers and some proprietary compilers (e.g., for embedded systems) are used.

Comment: Who is the "We" in *"We recommend ..."* from the "explained here" article?

Comment: Ehm... Microsoft?

Comment: Exactly, and it has a small downside on portability. While all mainstream compilers support `#pragma once` (at least I can't find one that doesn't), there are proprietary compilers for embedded systems that don't. So depending on what you are coding for and what compiler you are using, it may fail. `#ifndef ...` `#define ...` (content) `#endif` is supported by all. Worth a note (or comment).