# What is the reason for #pragma once inside header guards?

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor, header-files, pragma

Just seen this inside `<boost/asio.hpp>`

```
#ifndef BOOST_ASIO_HPP
#define BOOST_ASIO_HPP

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1200)
# pragma once
#endif // defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1200)

/// ....

#endif // BOOST_ASIO_HPP
```

Disregarding the `_MSC_VER` preprocessor checks, what is the benefit of having the `#pragma once` in this case? Doesn't the preprocessor header guard ensure in all cases and on all platforms, the header contents are only ever `included` once?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`#pragma once` specifies that the file will be included (opened) **only once** by the compiler when compiling a source code file. This can reduce build times as the compiler will not open and read the file after the first `#include` of the module.

If you don't `#pragma once`, the file will be **opened each time** it is needed and compiler will stop parsing it on `#ifndef BOOST_ASIO_HPP`, if it has been defined.

Comment: You saying the header is opened and read just the one time if we have #pragma? Header guards means file is always opened but contents within guards skipped, right? Is my understanding correct? If only I could demonstrate this so I see it happen :)

Comment: In case of #pragma once it is not always opened. This directive makes the compiler remember not to open it again (more than once). That's why this directive is superior to #ifndef, which could be omitted. However many people still use #ifndef to support old compilers that do not recognize #pragma once.

Answer (score 3):

[Specifies that the file will be included (opened) only once by the compiler in a build. This can reduce build times as the compiler will not open and read the file after the first #include of the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard)

And one more related question from  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard)

Comment: ok. I understand that purpose of header guards. Question is why we have header guard and pragma one

Comment: @MeThinks - maybe not all implementations support this pragma, so you still want to prevent your header from being processed multiple times. The pragma is an added benefit here.

Comment: A lot of it is answered in the SO link I gave in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes header guards ensures that the header contents are included only once. but here you are using #pragma for checking another definition and not include file.

The below link is existing question on header guards in SO.

[Purpose of Header guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979384/purpose-of-header-guards)

Comment: The header guard does this anyway, right? why need #pragma once as well?

Comment: The header guard tells the preprocessor that it must silent all lines in the file from the `#ifndef` to the `#endif`, but the preprocessor is assumed to read the whole file, and just output no result for the block. The `#pragma once` tells the preprocessor that any later `#include` that contains the same file is to be ignored. The difference is that in the latter case the preprocessor will not even open the file and check. That being said, `#pragma once` is not standard, and compilers have grown to understand the include guard pattern and there should be not much of a difference.

Comment: @MeThinks - maybe not all implementations support this pragma, so you still want to prevent your header from being processed multiple times. The pragma is an added benefit here. (comment duplicated from another answer)

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma once` has the same purpose, but include guards are intended to require a deeper analysis to ensure a file is included exactly once - e.g.

```
// somerandomfileinmyproject.cpp
#undef BOOST_ASIO_HPP 
#include <bost/asio.cpp>
```

Unless the compiler does handle such cases correctly, it still needs to open the file and pass it through the preprocessor even though it has been included before.

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce the effect of the `#pragma once` in a standard way using the following:

```
#if !defined GUARD_SYMBOL
#include "GUARDED_FILE"
#endif
```

although it is much more verbose. As others have said, it helps with compilation times since the file is not searched for / opened instead of opening the file and ignoring everything inside it - the file still has to be parsed by the preprocessor.

Comment: As David noted above, most modern compilers (esp. gcc) understands the header guard pattern well enough to skip the reparsing part, and act as if there was a pragma once or as if the code was written the way you show here.
This, and the fact that pragma once cannot correctly handle some corner cases is also the reason why pragma once has been actively rejected from beeing introduced into the new C++0x standard. 
see also this [SO disscussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard)