# Compile error "'struct' type redefinition" although it's the first definition for it

Tags: c++

Everything was working well untill I moved some code from the main file to a new class, then I had the following error:

> error C2011: 'color1' : 'struct' type redefinition

```
struct color1
{
    color1()
    {
        red = green = blue = 0;
    }

    color1(float _red, float _green, float _blue)
    {
        red = _red;
        green = _green;
        blue = _blue;
    }

    float red, green, blue;
};
```

Any idea ?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979384/purpose-of-header-guards

Comment: It's probably in a file that's being included twice. Add pragma guards to the file it's in.

Comment: Clearly there is more to your program than this. Would you please reduce your program to the smallest complete program that exhibits the error you see, and then post that program here?

Comment: ... Use constructor initializer lists, Luke ...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If the compiler says it's redefined, then it probably is.

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you moved the struct from a source file to a header file, and forget the include guards in that header, which is then included multiple times in a source file.

EDIT: As a general rule I generally suggest avoiding leading underscores. In some cases (for example followed by a capital letter) they're reserved for the implementation and it's simplest to just never use leading `_` instead of hoping you remember all the rules.

Comment: +1 for likely answer, and another +1 for underscore advice.  Unfortunately, capped at +1 overall.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of avoiding leading underscores. For reasons that are not clear to me I see so many programmers that keep using those names when a similar approach (but always legal and less dangerous) would be for example adding them at the end instead.

Answer (score 16):

From snippet above I can't deduce something is wrong.

But typically this error means that you are including same header files multiple times. Don't you forget to add standard guards for include files?

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_FILE_
#define MY_HEADER_FILE_

// here is your header file code

#endif
```

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I've taken a look on the answer above and thats sounds reasonable. Will also remove them from my own code))

Answer (score 10):

You can have the definition of the structure on a header file.
Have

```
 #pragma once
```

at the beginning of the header where the struct is defined, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and luckily did not take long figure out that it was just a silly mistake.

The thing was that I had a backup of my project at another drive (D:) but all the code was set on the drive C: when explicitly defined the full path. I created it on the C: path and was always using that way, but accidentally opened the project from the D and thought that it was the same thing, so at compile it was including twice because in some cases it was including the code from the C: path and at others from the D: path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too, and it turned out that I made a mistake with my header guard. For example, instead of writing:

```
#ifndef COMMAND_H
#define COMMAND_H

// My code

#endif // COMMAND_H
```

I made a little and hard to recognize typo:

```
#ifndef COMNAND_H
#define COMMAND_H

// My code

#endif // COMMAND_H
```

That is, COMNAND_H not COMMAND_H. It should be the letter M rather than the letter N. I fixed that and everything was fine. Hope this answer help you with your case!!!

Answer (score 0):

What caused this problem for me is that I had two header files (*A.h* and *B.h*) and I included (via `#include`) B.h into the header file of *A.h*, and I also included *A.h* into the header file of *B.h*.

Be removing the include one of the header files, the error disappeared.