# error C2011: 'member' : 'struct' type redefinition on moving a struct to a new header file

Tags: c++, boost

I had a .h file with some class code - overlay.h

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<boost/thread.hpp> 
    #include<vector>
    #include<boost/asio.hpp> 
    #include <string>
    #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp> 
    #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp> 
    #include <sstream> 
    #include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
    #include<member.h>
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

    class overlay_server{...};

struct member{
    std::string ip_address;
    short int port;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & ip_address;
        ar & port;
    }
};
```

Now I moved the struct to another new file called member.h
and included this file so my class overlay_server could use it.
Now when I build the program I get the error.

What changes should I make to make this work?
I read about header guards on SO, but couldnt really understand how to implement it here to solve the problem.

----edit----

member.h

```
struct member{
    std::string ip_address;
    short int port;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & ip_address;
        ar & port;
    }
};
```

run.cpp

```
    #include<overlay_server.h>
#include<overlay_client.h>

int main(){

    overlay_server overlay_server_(8002);
    boost::thread thread_(boost::bind(&overlay_server::member_list_server, overlay_server_));


    overlay_client overlay_client_("127.0.0.1",8002);
    overlay_client_.member_list_client();

    thread_.join();
}
```

I dont have redefinition of struct anywhere.
I have another class called overlay_client it also uses struct member.

In my main function, i create objects of both overlay_server and overlay_client.
Now my program runs only if member.h is included in overlay_server.h (though code in both overlay_server and overly_client requires it)
if its included in both then i get the redefinition error

why?

----edit----

this code in my member.h solves the issue
[Compile error "'struct' type redefinition" although it's the first definition for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825084/compile-error-struct-type-redefinition-although-its-the-first-definition-fo/5825130#5825130)

Comment: Have you cleaned the solution before you rebuild it?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Probably the error in the title.

Comment: have you messed with the include guards or is there multiple definition?by the way where have you defined the class? and you are using `<>` i think you better use `""` for custom headers

Comment: I havent yet written any include guards

Comment: "it also uses struct member". does overlay_client use `member` as a member data or inherits it? is overlay_client declared/defined in another file?

Comment: as a member data, and yes in another file

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `pragma` and get the same effect. At the top of *all* your header files, write:

```
#pragma once

rest of the header
 .
 .
 .
```

And the way to use include guards is to surround all the contents in a header file with an include guard, which looks like this:

```
// At the very top
#if !defined(SOME_SYMBOL)
#define SOME_SYMBOL

rest of the header
 .
 .
 .

// At the very bottom
#endif  // SOME_SYMBOL
```

Now, choosing a sensible name instead of `SOME_SYMBOL` is *very important*. Most programmers make a guard name based on the file name (and path and project name and company/individual name.) For example, for a header named "some_header.h" (or "SomeHeader.h") located in "[project root]/include/myproject", you would name the guard name to be `__INCLUDE__MY_PROJECT__SOME_HEADER_H__`. But this is just a suggestion; any unique symbol will do.

You can also combine the `pragma` and the include guards (because the `pragma` method *can* improve the compile time in very large projects, but not all compilers support it.) If you want them both, you'd write:

```
#pragma once

#if !defined(__INCLUDE__MY_PROJECT__SOME_HEADER_H__)
#define __INCLUDE__MY_PROJECT__SOME_HEADER_H__

rest of the header
 .
 .
 .

#endif  // __INCLUDE__MY_PROJECT__SOME_HEADER_H__
```

This has no adverse effects (to my knowledge,) only the potential to prevent build errors and to make your builds faster (on large projects.) But note that the meanings of include guards and `#pragma once` are **not** exactly the same. In very very rare cases, you would need to use one or the other, or neither.

Answer (score 1):

This is whats happening.
you have

`member.h`

included in `overlay_server.h` and in `overlay_client.h`

now when you include these two in main.cpp

it is like you are doing this in main.cpp(actually preprocessor expands like below)

```
#include"member.h"
#include"member.h"
```

so it typically will be like this after complete expansion

```
struct member{...};
struct member{...};    //redifinition!!
```

so the compiler parses it as being two definition of `struct member`(because it will visit member.h twice and read the def of member struct).

what to do to avoid this

in member.h add this

```
#ifndef MEMBER_DECL    //initially not defined
#define MEMBER_DECL    //include guard(now first time you enter this MEMBER_DECL will get defined. so second time compiler comes here it skips this.)
struct member
{
 //rest here
};

#endif
```

now in main you will have this

```
#include"member.h" //when this happens MEMBER_DECL is defined
```

so

```
//#include"member.h" member will not be expanded again hence resolving your redfinition
```

Answer (score 0):

If `overlay.h` contains a `struct member` definition and `member.h` also has a `struct member` definition, you cant include `member.h` from `overlay.h`. Here is how include guards work though:

```
        #include<iostream>
        #include<boost/thread.hpp> 
        #include<vector>
        #include<boost/asio.hpp> 
        #include <string>
        #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
        #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp> 
        #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp> 
        #include <sstream> 
        #include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
        #include<member.h>
   #ifndef _H__MEMBER_
   #define _H__MEMBER_
        using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
        class overlay_server{...};

    struct member{
        std::string ip_address;
        short int port;

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & ip_address;
            ar & port;
        }
    };
#endif
```

Notice the  `#ifndef _H__MEMBER_` and `#define _H__MEMBER_` and `#endif`. With the include guards, it makes sure your header is only included once because after the first time it's included *H*_MEMBER_ will be already defined so it will skip the definition. Your naming convention can be different but usually I do something along the lines of `_H__<HEADER NAME>_` as my defines.

Comment: As for your "Why?". You get a redefinition error because you included the same definition twice. Header guards prevent that from happening. Also sometimes you can just put struct member; in overly_client.h for example and then #include<member.h> in overlay_client.cpp

Comment: @Brad Why do you put the include guards after the `#include` statements? Is there a reason? As far as I can tell, that only makes the builds slower because the compiler will probably have to open those included files, only to encounter more include guards and close the files and leave them. Why not put the `#include` statements *inside* the include guards?

Comment: @yzt you make a good point, I guess I just put the guards below the includes for readability--I always like to have my includes at the very top of the file. It's more of a personal choice where you put the include guards.

Comment: @Brad I think putting `#include` statements outside of header guards can have a measurable impact on compile time in large projects. For that reason, I don't think it's a matter of personal taste and choice.