# Boost Log crashes on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, logging, boost, crash

Has anybody used boost log on iOS ? 
For me it's crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line 34 attribute_get_valule_impl.cpp if common attributes were added,
and with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line 267 attribute_value_set.cpp if not added.

Trivial logging is working good.
I'm trying to init logger as described in this question : 
[how to use boost log from multiple files with Gloa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086754/how-to-use-boost-log-from-multiple-files-with-gloa/22068278#22068278)
And also try the tutorial from official documentation.

I'm using boost 1.5.8 and also tried 1.5.9

**UPDATE** Code which I'm trying to run :
*Logging.h:*

```
#ifndef logging_hpp
#define logging_hpp

#include "boost/log/expressions.hpp"
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup.hpp>

#define INFO  BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::info)
#define WARN  BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::warning)
#define ERROR BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::error)

#define SYS_LOGFILE             "/var/log/example.log"

//Narrow-char thread-safe logger.
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> logger_t;

//declares a global logger with a custom initialization
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(my_logger, logger_t)

#endif
```

*Logging.cpp :*

```
    #include "Logging.h"

namespace attrs   = boost::log::attributes;
namespace expr    = boost::log::expressions;
namespace logging = boost::log;

//Defines a global logger initialization routine
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(my_logger, logger_t)
{
    logger_t lg;

    logging::add_common_attributes();

    logging::add_console_log(
            std::cout,
            boost::log::keywords::format = (
                    expr::stream << expr::format_date_time<     boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                    << " [" << expr::attr<     boost::log::trivial::severity_level >("Severity") << "]: "
                    << expr::smessage
            )
    );

    return lg;
}
```

*AppDelegate.mm* (where I'm using logging):

```
#include "Logging.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    INFO << "My Log Message";
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a code example.

Comment: @GrigoriyChudnov added sample code

Comment: I don't understand how you are including C++ in an Objective-C source file?

Comment: @trojanfoe read about Objective-C++ then.

Comment: Well at the time of my comment the source file had the file extension `.m` which is Objective-C, not Objective-C++.  So that would be "yes I'm using Objective-C++, not Objective-C".

Comment: @trojanfoe maybe I had checked compile all as Objective-C++ in my project settings, now corrected extension to `.mm`, to reduce misunderstandings.