# Proper way to declare and use structures in C project?

Tags: c, file, header, structure

I am building a project that I am trying to organize as follows:

```
main.c
globals.h
structures.h
FunctionSet1.c, FunctionSet1.h
FunctionSet2.c, FunctionSet2.h
etc.
```

I thought I could define a structure type in structures.h:

```
struct type_struct1 {int a,b;}; // define type 'struct type_struct1'
```

then declare a `function1()` returning a structure of type `type_struct1` in FunctionSet1.h:

```
#include "structures.h"
struct type_struct1 function1(); // declare function1() that returns a type 'struct type_struct1'
```

then write `function1()` in FunctionSet1.c:

```
#include "FunctionSet1.h"
struct type_struct1 function1() {
  struct type_struct1 struct1; // declare struct1 as type 'struct type_struct1'
  struct1.a=1;
  struct1.b=2;
  return struct1;
}
```

*Edit: with the corrected code above, the compiler returns*

```
306 'struct' tag redefined 'type_struct1' structures.h
```

Is the file set good practice ?
What is the good practice to manage the structures ?

Comment: Did you write include guards to your header files?

Comment: Also please include the error messages so we can stop guessing.

Comment: I did not because I don't know how to use them yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile error "'struct' type redefinition" although it's the first definition for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825084/compile-error-struct-type-redefinition-although-its-the-first-definition-fo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general structure looks good.  One thing you need to do, as zenith mentioned, is to put include guards into your header files.  What that is is a set of #define's that make sure that the contents of the header are not included more that once in a given file.  For example:

structures.h:

```
#ifndef STRUCTURES_H
#define STRUCTURES_H

struct type_struct1{
    int a,b;
};

...
// more structs
...

#endif
```

FunctionSet1.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_SET_1_H
#define FUNCTION_SET_1_H

#include "structures.h"

struct type_struct1 function1();

...
// more functions in FucntionSet1.c
...

#endif
```

main.c:

```
#inlcude <stdio.h>
#include "structures.h"
#include "FunctionSet1.h"

int main(void)
{
    struct type_struct1 struct1;
    struct1 = function1();
    return 0;
}
```

Here, main.c includes structures.h and FunctionSet1.h, but FunctionSet1.h also includes structures.h.  Without the include guards, the contents of structures.h would appear twice in the resulting file after the preprocesser is done.  This is probably why you're getting the "tag redefined" error.

The include guards prevent these type of errors from happening.  Then you don't have to worry about whether or not a particular header file was included or not.  This is particularly important if you're writing a library, where other users may not know the relationship between your header files.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you declare a structure named type_struct in structure.h, then in FunctionSet1.h the structure that you are returning is type_struct, and in the .c it is called struct1.

So i think that the problem is that struct1 and type_struct are not recognized because they have never been defined ...

However, the organization of your files is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought the line in structures.h defined a structure type, but not an actual structure, hence the declaration of struct1 in FunctionSet1.c as a structure of type struct type_struct1. I didn't know in Functionset1.h if I should put the type name (type_struct1) or the structure name (struct1).

Comment: @PoleAco Functions need to be declared to return _types_. The name of the actual object returned is irrelevant. So in FunctionSet1.c declare to function to return the type `type_struct1`.

Comment: @zenith I updated my code accordingly (if I understood correctly).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to declare the structure in your `file.h` (you can use `typedef` to create an alias)

```
   typedef struct   Books
   {
      char          title[50];
      int           book_id;
   } books;
```

then, you have to include your `file.h` in your `file.c` and declare your variable like this

```
#include "file.h"

int       main()
{
    books book1;

    book1.title = "Harry Potter";
    book1.book_id = 54;
}
```

or like this if you didn't use `typedef`

```
#include "file.h"

int              main()
{
    struct Books book1;

    book1.title = "Harry Potter";
    book1.book_id = 54;
}
```

Comment: I feel this is how I've done it. Would you point to my error more specifically ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

I read again what you said and found that the code above is now correct.
The error I report is with testing the following main.c

```
#include "structures.h"
#include "FunctionSet1.h"
void main() {
  struct type_struct1 struct2;
  struct2=function1();
}
```

in which structures.h is included again, thus causing the error. Removing the include eliminates the error.

I will now look into header guards to avoid such problems.

Thanks again.

Comment: @dbush : wow got it without even seeing the main.c. Indeed you are right and I will do as you (all) advise.