# How do I define the same named structure in more than one class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've got multiple classes from multiple engineers which I am using and they have the same named structures in the classes. From this I get the error "'struct' type redefinition". How do I get around this?

Example:

```
// Eng1Class.h
#pragma once

struct Eng1And2SameName
{
    unsigned int bottle;
};

class Eng1Class
{
public:
    Eng1Class();
    ~Eng1Class();
};
```

.

```
// Eng2Class.h
#pragma once

struct Eng1And2SameName
{
    float x, y;
};

class Eng2Class
{
public:
    Eng2Class();
    ~Eng2Class();
};
```

.

```
// Main Program
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Eng1Class.h"
#include "Eng2Class.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Error: error C2011: 'Eng1And2SameName' : 'struct' type redefinition

According to this [Compile error "'struct' type redefinition" although it's the first definition for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825084/compile-error-struct-type-redefinition-although-its-the-first-definition-fo) the #pragma once should fix the issues, but I still see the error. Any insights you can provide?

Comment: What is the point of these `struct`s?  If they are solely for the class then you can declare them inside the class.

Comment: Defining a Namespace will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `#pragma once` prevents the header files from being included more than once - each is included once -> redefinition.

> they have the same named structures in the classes

*header files

The're not defined inside the classes (nested), but they could be:

```
class Eng1Class
{
public:
    struct Eng1And2SameName
    {
        unsigned int bottle;
    };

    Eng1Class();
    ~Eng1Class();
};
```

Or you could enclose the contents of those headers into two differently named `namespace`s.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a namespace would help

For example as you said error with same struct definition in same namescope .
Reports error
[image]

You can do it by defining namesapce

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace Eng1 {
    struct Eng1And2SameName
    {
        unsigned int bottle;

    };
}

namespace Eng2
{

    struct Eng1And2SameName
    {
        float x, y;
    };
}

int main()
{
    Eng1::Eng1And2SameName a;
    Eng2::Eng1And2SameName b;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually engineers working on the same product are coordinated somehow, at least they will use a common source code repository and a common build. Hence, conflicts should have come up earlier.

"uncoordinated" engineers may happen when they work on different products, and if so, each product could have its own namespace. Thereby, you can combine the products without having conflicts:

```
// in a header:
namespace Eng1Class {

    struct Eng1And2SameName
    {
        unsigned int bottle;
    };

    class EngClass
    {
    public:
        EngClass();
        ~EngClass();
    };

}

// in the cpp-file
Eng1Class::EngClass::EngClass() {
    cout << "hello, Class 1";
}

// in another (or even the same) header
namespace Eng2Class {

    struct Eng1And2SameName
    {
        float x, y;
    };

    class EngClass
    {
    public:
        EngClass();
        ~EngClass();
    };
}

// in another (or even the same) cpp-file
Eng2Class::EngClass::EngClass() {
    cout << "hello, Class 2";
}
```