# Clang complaining about (Or not recognising) "extern" of an object instance of a class

Tags: c++, clang

I am trying to build a very small "attempt" of an executable program on Windows that is run by getting it linked to a shared library .dll file.

I am declaring an `extern` instance object of a class and "defining" it in another .cpp file (which includes the header file that is containing the extern declaration).

EntryPoint.h

```
// Here is the "extern" instance 

extern Application* CreateApp();

int main(argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = CreateApp();
    app->Run();
}
```

Launcher.cpp

```
#include "EntryPoint.h"
#include "Application.h"

class __declspec(dllimport) Launcher : public Application
{
  public:
    Launcher() {};
    ~Launcher() {};
};

// Here is the definition

Application* CreateApp()
{
    return new Launcher();
}
```

Application.h

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Application
{
  public:
    Application();
    ~Application();

    void Run();
}

// To be defined in the "Launcher.cpp" file
Application* CreateApp();
```

Application.cpp

```
#include "application.h"

void Application::Run()
{
    while(true) {}
}
```

After I have compiled "Application.cpp" as a ".dll" file (Application.dll) , I then tried to compile "Launcher.cpp" file + link it to that .dll file

```
clang++ -o launcher.exe launcher.cpp -l application.dll
```

And also tried

```
clang++ launcher.cpp application.dll
```

Then Clang complains:

> ```
> In file included from launcher.cpp:1:
> ./EntryPoint.h:4:8: error: unknown type name 'Application'
> extern Application* CreateApp();
>        ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

There was one solution"ish" I tried and "kinda" resolved the complain, which for me is not really the fix I am looking for or anyone else's in my opinion.

If I included "Application.h" inside the "EntryPoint.h" then that will not cause the Clang compiler to complain about it and will proceed to a successful compilation. But then isn't "Application.h" already included altogether with "EntryPoint.h" from the beginning? As you can see "Launcher.cpp" is already including both of them so they should be seeing each other right?

Comment: The source file where `main` is defined needs a full definition of `Application` type; since it calls a method on it. Also, it doesn't make sense to define `main` in a header file.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What type it could be for `Application`? You see where it was first declared in `Application.h` it has no type and it's just a forward declaration, right?  What other ways to define `main` outside the executable source file? Also thank you for your wonderful reply!

Comment: The source file that contains `int main() {...}` needs to `#include "Application.h"`. Because otherwise the compiler can't know the class has a method named `Run()`, and doesn't know what to do with `app->Run();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am declaring an `extern` instance object of a class [...]

That's not what you're doing with `extern`.

> ```cpp
> extern Application* CreateApp();
> ```

The `extern` specifier applies to what is being declared, i.e. `CreateApp`. It just means that the function has external linkage, and that's the default already, so `extern` has no effect here.

You could make the definition of `Application` available at the point where `CreateApp` is delcared, which means `#include "Application.h"` before `CreateApp()`.
However, this might be a bit excessive.

> ```cpp
> #include "EntryPoint.h"
> #include "Application.h"
> ```
>
> But then isn't "Application.h" already included altogether with "EntryPoint.h" from the beginning?

Order matters a lot in C++. `Application.h` is included *after* `EntryPoint.h`, so nothing in `Application.h` is visible to `EntryPoint.h`. Changing the order would be a very unrealiable solution. If including `Application.h` in `EntryPoint.h` works for you, do it.

Alternatively, you could use forward declarations.

```cpp
// EntryPoint.h

// elaborated type specifiers
class Application* CreateApp();

// or more commonly, people do this:
class Applicaton;
Application* CreateApp();
```

Instead of putting the forward declaration `class Application` directly inside `EntryPoint.h`, you could also create a *forwarding header* `ApplicationFwd.h` that contains only `class Application;` and is included by `EntryPoint.h`.

No matter what you do, it's important that a header always includes or forward-declares its dependencies, instead of relying on include order.

#### Further notes

- `main` should not be located in a header file; move it into a source file like `main.cpp`
- make sure to add include guards or `#pragma once` to all your headers (see [What is the purpose of include guards in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979384/5740428))

Comment: Heeey the order of the included files in `Launcher.cpp` did it for me!  Thanks a lot! But now it opened the entirety of things at me and wanting to ask about how to know what is the correct order of files I should go with? I am just imagining if I have 10 other files for example, then how can I know what goes first and what goes last? Btw: The fix not only fixed the main problem but also now I can get away without including `Application.h` file into `EntryPoint.h` Yaaay ^^

Comment: @pk6x if it's not clear from the answer; I'm not really recommending to fix this through the order of includes. *Technically*, include order does matter in C++, but code which relies on it is very difficult to understand. Imagine if it mattered whether you included `<vector>` or `<string>` first; that would be confusing. You should use forward-declarations like the solution describes. All headers should include or forward-declare what they need; they shouldn't rely on their includer having put them in some order.

Comment: Where should the forward declaration be at exactly? Because as you can see from the mess I just did Application* CreateApp(); has been declared in both `Application.h` and `EntryPoint.h` header files AND defined in `Launcher.cpp`. I see you have suggested to do it in a new separate header file `ApplicationFwd.h` but can't  that be done without it? Also, what if I just included `Application.h` in `EntryPoint.h` ? Because that also can fix it. I mean from the perspective of good practice.

Comment: @pk6x the forward declaration should be in `EntryPoint.h` or in `ApplicationFwd.h`, included by the former. I've updated the question to elaborate on this. Also follow the link explaining the purpose of include guards. Include guard would prevent declaring `CreateApp()` multiple times. Actually, declaring it multiple times wouldn't be an issue though, since you're allowed to do that. You just aren't allowed to define it multiple times. Regardless, use include guards. Also, it can be done with/without forwarding headers; that's up to personal preference.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking again, is the forward declaration of class Application in `EntryPoint.h` as you suggested is to replace the use of `extern` specifier? You see I am asking because honestly I am following a tutorial on YT so I'm not sure if by him using `extern` in this context is rightful or not, or the entire program files structure is also wrong.  Also thanks for the include guard tip! I can see myself using it everywhere hahaha. One last thing, big thing, can you elaborate more on that the header always includes or forwarded-declares its dependencies?

Comment: @pk6x yes, `extern` is pointless in this case, and you can remove it. The general rule of thumb is that every header should include everything it needs, so that the header could be included at any location (even at the very beginning of the cpp file, as the very first thing), and it would still work.

Comment: @JanSchultke Yes totally makes sense now. If every header file includes everything it needs then the order of included files wouldn't matter anymore, am I right?

Comment: @pk6x yes, it would be a way to ensure that order doesn't matter, and that would be good. The fact that `#include` order matters in the first place is a major problem and goes against developer intuition. The order of `import`s in e.g. Java doesn't matter for example.